# How to retrieve the assembly version of System.ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, nuget

Where/How can I retrieve the "real" assembly version of the System.ValueTuple.dll ?

When I download either one of the nuget packages

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/4.3.0
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/4.5.0

And try to retrieve the binary version of these two files

```
Assembly.LoadFile(file).FullName;
```

I retrieve for both binaries the same entry:

```
System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
```

Background for the question: I wanted to fix some binding redirections and stumbled upon this entry:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

And version 4.0.3.0 didn't match with the deployed version 4.0.0.0 what made me curios.

Comment: Have you thought about upgrading Framework version

Comment: Use `Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(file).Name.Version` with Mono.Cecil nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)` and `Assembly.LoadFile(...)` output the wrong assembly version. (I suspect that if the assembly was already loaded...).

I digged around in the Assembly Namespace and found `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(pathToAssembly).Version` to correctly display the assembly version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check out if below code helps:

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("System.ValueTuple.dll");
            Version ver = assembly.GetName().Version;
            Console.WriteLine(ver);
```

Check the properties for dll:
[image]

Comment: The properties window shows the correct version - but for some reason the code still outputs 4.0.0.0.